# Dynamically formating an input to clock-time

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small clock application and I wanted a clean input for time. I don't want to use the native type="time" element because of browser inconsistency, and type="number" doesn't allow a colon. So I settled on **type="text"** and have written formatting rules that restrict the text input to valid clock times.

It must work as the user types, formatting the text for them as they go. My rules work but are a cluster of **if** and **regex**. I'm new to this, so I'm assuming I've made a mess of things. Can you think of a cleaner or more efficient way to achieve the same results?

### Formatting Rules

- There must be only [0-9] or ":" allowed in the input.
- Control keys must still work (Enter, Delete, Alt...)
- There must be exactly one ":".
- Preceding the ":" must be one or two digits
- Following must be exactly two digits.
- The last two digits (minutes) must be less than 60
- For 24 Hour clocks the first digit(s) must be less than 25
- For 12 Hour clocks the first digit(s) must be less than 13 *(global.dayNight)*

### Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/x99btgez/

*//While their are lots of question on formatting clock time, I didn't see anything in Javascript that formats the type as the user types.*

```
let ele = document.getElementById("wut");
let global = {};
global.dayNight = false; // 12 Hour or 24 Hour clock
document.getElementById("wut").addEventListener('keydown', filterTimeInput);
document.getElementById("wut").addEventListener('blur', cancel);

function submitInput() {
  if (!ele.value.match(/:/)) { // in the event they typed 3 numbers and left out the ":"
    ele.value =  ele.value.slice(0, -2) +":"+ ele.value.slice(-2)
  }
}

function cancel() {
  ele.value = "";
}

function filterTimeInput(evt) {

  let key; key = evt.key;

  if (key === "Enter") { submitInput(); }
  if (key === "Escape") { cancel(); }

  if (key.length === 1) { // Exclude non number characteres. I avoided a [^] match to leave operational keys enabled.
    if(key.match(/[A-Za-z\s\.\\\+\*\?\^\$\[\]\{\}\(\)\|\/\-&~!@#%`="><_',;]|Decimal|Multiply|Add|Divide|Subtract|Seperator/)) evt.preventDefault();
  }

  if (ele.value.match(/:/)) { // Prevents users from typing ":" twice, or from typing 3 digits of minutes
    if(key.match(/:/)) evt.preventDefault();
    if(ele.value.match(/:[0-9]{2}/)) {
      if(key.match(/[0-9]/)) evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  if (global.dayNight) { // 24 hour clock
    if (ele.value.length === 0) { // first number should be 1, 2 or counted as earlier than 10:00
      if (key.match(/[3-9]/)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ele.value = "0" + key + ":";
      } else if (key.match(/:/)) { // If they type a ":" first thing
        evt.preventDefault();
        ele.value = "00" + key;
      }
    } else if (ele.value.length === 1) { // If the first number was a 2, the second number should be less than 4
      if (ele.value === "2") {
        if (key.match(/[5-9]/)) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          ele.value += "0:" + key;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  else if (global.dayNight === false) { // 12 hour clock
    if (ele.value.length === 0) { // First number should be 0 or 1, or counted as earlier than 10:00
      if (key.match(/[2-9]/)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ele.value = "0" + key + ":";
      } else if (key.match(/:/)) { // If they type a ":" first thing
        evt.preventDefault();
        ele.value = "00" + key;
      }
    } else if (ele.value === "1") { // Second number following a 1 should less than 3 or treated as minutes
      if (key.match(/[3-9]/)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ele.value += "0:" + key;
      }
    }
  }

  if (ele.value.match(/:$/)) { // Prevents a number greater than 5 following a ":"
    if (key.match(/[6-9]/)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      ele.value += "0" + key;
    }
  }

  if (ele.value.match(/[0-9]{3}/)) { // If a user types 4 numbers without a ":" then adds ":" for them.
    if (key.match(/[0-9]/)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      ele.value = ele.value.slice(0,2) + ":" + ele.value.slice(2,3) + key
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use some plugins like TimePicket or Mask to restrict user actions *and* have already tested and maintainable code?

Comment: @Justinas I checked out Mask. For one it uses jQuery and I am not. And its hour field doesn't meet all of my requirements. I googled TimePicket but came up with nothing.